# Screen reader (voiceover) don't read aria-describedby text when it contains an unordered list

Tags: html, accessibility, voiceover, screen-readers

I'm using voiceover on MacOS and the latest version of Safari. If I do the following then the described text is not read out when on one of the radio button.

```
<fieldset aria-describedby="described">
  <legend>Legend</legend>
  <div id="described"><ul><li>described text</li></ul></div>
  
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="question-2" id="question-2-yes" value="yes">
    <label for="question-2-yes">Yes</label>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="question-2" id="question-2-no" value="no">
    <label for="question-2-no">No</label>
  </div>
    
</fieldset>
```

However if the text isn't in a list then it is read out like follows

```
<fieldset aria-describedby="described">
  <legend>Legend</legend>
  <div id="described">described text</div>
  
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="question-2" id="question-2-yes" value="yes">
    <label for="question-2-yes">Yes</label>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="question-2" id="question-2-no" value="no">
    <label for="question-2-no">No</label>
  </div>
    
</fieldset>
```

Is there any way around this? I need the described by text to be in a list format.

**Edit:** the format of the fieldset is in question form where the description is integral to the question, see an example here:

```
<form>
  <h2>Question 1</h2>
  <fieldset aria-describedby="eligibility-quiz-description-1">
    <legend>Are you applying for any of the following:</legend>
    <div id="eligibility-quiz-description-1">
      <ul>
        <li>One off or annual events e.g. festivals and galas</li>
        <li>Sponsorship</li>
        <li>Feasibility and development studies</li>
        <li>Round-robin fundraising appeals</li>
        <li>Endowment appeals</li>
        <li>Animal welfare charities</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div>                   
      <input type="radio" name="question-1" id="question-1-yes" value="yes">
      <label for="question-1-yes">Yes</label>
    </div>

    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="question-1" id="question-1-no" value="no">
      <label for="question-1-no">No</label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: [from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-describedby): "Note: The aria-describedby content should only be a text string. If there are important underlying semantics in the content, consider using aria-details.".

Comment: While this might be a practical recommendation, the [ARIA standard](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#aria-describedby) explicitly mentions that the description can _provide more verbose information_ and that it’s possible to _enclose a set of elements (e.g., paragraphs) with the element referenced by the ID_. Practical support by assistive technology might vary, of course.

Comment: @tay Would you mind explaining why conveying the structure is important? Have you tried assigning each `<li>` as a single description to provoke pauses? `<fieldset aria-describedby="li1 li2 li3 …">…<ul><li id="li1">…</li> <li id="li2">…</li> …`

Comment: Thanks for clearing things up. I still don’t get why it’s important to have the structure preserved. If the list is read as a flat string it’s still comprehensible. Not perfect, but sufficient, I’d say. And wouldn’t rendering the description a list of checkboxes be even more user friendly? Otherwise they need to retain all heard cases in memory to reply yes or no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I resolved it in my case. I had no control over what would be added to the description as it came from a CMS' WYSIWYG area. So I restructured the HTML so the whole thing wasn't wrapped in a fieldset, changed the legend to a heading and then added a summary question and used that as the radio legend instead. Example as follows:

```
<form>
  <h2>Question 1</h2>

  <h3>We are not able to fund any of the following:</h3>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>One off or annual events e.g. festivals and galas</li>
      <li>Sponsorship</li>
      <li>Feasibility and development studies</li>
      <li>Round-robin fundraising appeals</li>
      <li>Endowment appeals</li>
      <li>Animal welfare charities</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Can you confirm that you are not applying for any of the above?</legend>
    <div>                   
      <input type="radio" name="question-1" id="question-1-yes" value="yes">
      <label for="question-1-yes">Yes</label>
    </div>

    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="question-1" id="question-1-no" value="no">
      <label for="question-1-no">No</label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Robin mentioned, there is a better suited attribute for your purpose: `aria-details`. Please test it and let us know.

The [ARIA standard](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#aria-description) provides the following guidance on using `aria-describedby` (the emphasis is mine):

> - Authors SHOULD use `aria-describedby` when the related description or annotation elements contain a simple, small description that is best experienced as a flat string, rather than by having the user navigate to them.
> - Authors SHOULD use `aria-details` when the related description or annotation elements **contain useful semantics or structure**, or there is a lot of content within them, making it difficult to experience as a flat string. Using `aria-details` will allow assistive technology users to visit the structured content and provide additional navigation commands, making it easier to understand the structure, or to experience the information in smaller pieces.

The `aria-details` attribute would add details to the `<fieldset>`, which has a `group` role. Those are usually announced only once you enter the group, not on every input focus. Whether the screen reader will consider details when announcing a group context is yet another question.

If this are in fact important details for each input, you’d better add it to each one individually, like `<input type="radio" aria-details="described" …>`

```html
<fieldset aria-details="described">
  <legend>Legend</legend>
  <div id="described"><ul><li>described text</li></ul></div>
  
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="question-2" id="question-2-yes" value="yes">
    <label for="question-2-yes">Yes</label>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="question-2" id="question-2-no" value="no">
    <label for="question-2-no">No</label>
  </div>
    
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tested aria-details on Safari on MacOS with VoiceOver but unfortunately it doesn't read it out when focused on the input. This is the same whether the attribute is added to the fieldset or the inputs themselves.

Comment: I guess I checked support too quickly. [Screen Reader support](https://a11ysupport.io/tech/aria/aria-details_attribute) seems to be non-existent on mobile. So I guess that you don’t have a way to add a structure. Could you explain why this is important?

Comment: I have updated the original question with an example